# Android Volley Listview onclicklistener

Tags: android, android-volley

Firnds I am using Android Volley Library to fetch data from json

I have successfully integrated this part but unable to click on on item

[image]

my code id

UpcomingJourney.java

```
package com.mssinfotech.dropjourney;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Cache;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.mssinfotech.dropjourney.adapter.UpcommingJourneyListAdapter;
import com.mssinfotech.dropjourney.app.AppController;
import com.mssinfotech.dropjourney.data.FeedItem;
import com.mssinfotech.dropjourney.data.UpcommingJourneyFeedItem;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class UpcomingJourney extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static final String TAG = UpcomingJourney.class.getSimpleName();
    private ListView listView;
    private UpcommingJourneyListAdapter listAdapter;
    private List<UpcommingJourneyFeedItem> feedItems;
    private DBHelper mydb;
    private static String id="";
    private String URL_FEED = "";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mydb = new DBHelper(this);
        Cursor MyData = mydb.getMyData();
        MyData.moveToFirst();
        id = MyData.getString(MyData.getColumnIndex("id"));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upcoming_journey);

        Toolbar mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
        mActionBarToolbar.setTitle("Up-comming Journey");

        setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        URL_FEED = CommonUtilities.API_URL+"?type=DriverUpcommingJourney&vid="+id;
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        feedItems = new ArrayList<UpcommingJourneyFeedItem>();
        listAdapter = new UpcommingJourneyListAdapter(this, feedItems);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        listView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You clicked"+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
        // We first check for cached request
        Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
        Cache.Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FEED);
        Log.d("url mss",URL_FEED);
        if (entry != null) {
            // fetch the data from cache
            try {
                String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
                try {
                    parseJsonFeed(new JSONObject(data));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            // making fresh volley request and getting json
            JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                    URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                    if (response != null) {
                        parseJsonFeed(response);
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                }
            });
            // Adding request to volley request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
        }
    }
    private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");
            String ststus=response.getString("status");
            if(ststus.equals("success")) {
                for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

                    UpcommingJourneyFeedItem item = new UpcommingJourneyFeedItem();
                    item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
                    item.setName(feedObj.getString("name"));

                    // Image might be null sometimes
                    String image = feedObj.isNull("image") ? null : feedObj
                            .getString("image");
                    item.setImge(image);
                    item.setStatus(feedObj.getString("status"));
                    item.setProfilePic(feedObj.getString("profilePic"));
                    item.setTimeStamp(feedObj.getString("timeStamp"));
                    // url might be null sometimes
                    String feedUrl = feedObj.isNull("url") ? null : feedObj
                            .getString("url");
                    item.setUrl(feedUrl);
                    feedItems.add(item);

                    // notify data changes to list adapater
                    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }else{
                LinearLayout layone= (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.errorImage);// change id here
                layone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

UpcommingJourneyListAdapter.java

```
package com.mssinfotech.dropjourney.adapter;
import com.mssinfotech.dropjourney.FeedImageView;
import com.mssinfotech.dropjourney.R;
import com.mssinfotech.dropjourney.app.AppController;
import com.mssinfotech.dropjourney.data.UpcommingJourneyFeedItem;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.format.DateUtils;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;

public class UpcommingJourneyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<UpcommingJourneyFeedItem> feedItems;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    public UpcommingJourneyListAdapter(Activity activity, List<UpcommingJourneyFeedItem> feedItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.feedItems = feedItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return feedItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return feedItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView timestamp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
        TextView statusMsg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtStatusMsg);
        TextView url = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtUrl);
        NetworkImageView profilePic = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
        FeedImageView feedImageView = (FeedImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.feedImage1);

        UpcommingJourneyFeedItem item = feedItems.get(position);

        name.setText(item.getName());

        // Converting timestamp into x ago format
        CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                Long.parseLong(item.getTimeStamp()),
                System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
        timestamp.setText(timeAgo);

        // Chcek for empty status message
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getStatus())) {
            statusMsg.setText(item.getStatus());
            statusMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // status is empty, remove from view
            statusMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // Checking for null feed url
        if (item.getUrl() != null) {
            url.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + item.getUrl() + "\">" + item.getUrl() + "</a> "));
            // Making url clickable
            url.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            url.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // url is null, remove from the view
            url.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // user profile pic
        profilePic.setImageUrl(item.getProfilePic(), imageLoader);

        // Feed image
        if (item.getImge() != null) {
            feedImageView.setImageUrl(item.getImge(), imageLoader);
            feedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            feedImageView
                    .setResponseObserver(new FeedImageView.ResponseObserver() {
                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            feedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

AppController.java

```
package com.mssinfotech.dropjourney.app;

import com.mssinfotech.dropjourney.volley.LruBitmapCache;
import android.app.Application;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    LruBitmapCache mLruBitmapCache;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        getRequestQueue();
        if (mImageLoader == null) {
            getLruBitmapCache();
            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue, mLruBitmapCache);
        }

        return this.mImageLoader;
    }

    public LruBitmapCache getLruBitmapCache() {
        if (mLruBitmapCache == null)
            mLruBitmapCache = new LruBitmapCache();
        return this.mLruBitmapCache;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

UpcommingJourneyFeedItem.java

```
package com.mssinfotech.dropjourney.data;

public class UpcommingJourneyFeedItem {
    private int id;
    private String name, status, image, profilePic, timeStamp, url;

    public UpcommingJourneyFeedItem() {
    }

    public UpcommingJourneyFeedItem(int id, String name, String image, String status,
                                    String profilePic, String timeStamp, String url) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
        this.status = status;
        this.profilePic = profilePic;
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImge() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImge(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getProfilePic() {
        return profilePic;
    }

    public void setProfilePic(String profilePic) {
        this.profilePic = profilePic;
    }

    public String getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }

    public void setTimeStamp(String timeStamp) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

LruBitmapCache.java

```
package com.mssinfotech.dropjourney.volley;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.ImageCache;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;

public class LruBitmapCache extends LruCache<String, Bitmap> implements
        ImageCache {
    public static int getDefaultLruCacheSize() {
        final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
        final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

        return cacheSize;
    }

    public LruBitmapCache() {
        this(getDefaultLruCacheSize());
    }

    public LruBitmapCache(int sizeInKiloBytes) {
        super(sizeInKiloBytes);
    }

    @Override
    protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
        return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight() / 1024;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        return get(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
        put(url, bitmap);
    }
}
```

activity_upcoming_journey.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.mssinfotech.dropjourney.UpcomingJourney">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/headBars"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <ListView
        android:layout_below="@+id/headBars"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@null" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:id="@+id/errorImage"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:background="@drawable/ic_mood_bad_black_24dp"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp" />
        <TextView
            android:textColor="#ccc"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="No Ride found"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#f00"
            android:text="No Record Found"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

feed_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/feed_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_parent_rounded_corner"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right" >

            <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/profilePic"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/feed_item_profile_pic"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/feed_item_profile_pic"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" >
            </com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_profile_info_padd" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/feed_item_profile_name"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/timestamp"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/timestamp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/feed_item_timestamp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtStatusMsg"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_top" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtUrl"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
            android:textColorLink="@color/link" />
        <com.mssinfotech.dropjourney.FeedImageView
            android:id="@+id/feedImage1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Change listView.setOnItemSelectedListener to listView.setOnItemClickListener and try?

Comment: no its not working do you have any other suggetion http://prntscr.com/d704md

Comment: Can u post your updated code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setOnItemClickListener` instead of `setOnItemSelectedListener` on ListView.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You clicked"+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
```

Comment: Its not working when i click on item noting happened please confirm what i do. I post complete code

Comment: Use `UpcomingJourney.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()` in Toast.

Answer (score 0):

It is not "setOnItemSelectedListener". Use listView.setOnItemClickListener(this) instead.

Answer (score 0):

**listView.setOnItemSelectedListener** is prefer to use spinner list so, for list view you have to use instead of that **listView.setOnItemClickListener**

Answer (score 0):

For **capturing click events** on `ListView` you should use `onItemClickListener` instead of `onItemSelectedListener`. So in your code replace `setOnItemSelectedListener` with `setOnItemClickListener`

Comment: Its not working when i click on item noting happened please confirm what i do. I post complete code

Answer (score 0):

friend thanks for your support but nothing works
now finaly I found solution

You should define on all of the child objects in the item listview (TextView, ImageView etc.):

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

And for the root item RelativeLayout / LinearLayout and so, define:

```
android:clickable="false"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

And it works now